# Meaning of $. \wedge t$ (. \wedge t) in stochastic analysis

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In [Viscosity Solutions of Fully Nonlinear Parabolic Path Dependent PDEs: Part I](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.0006) they define (on page 4) a metric :

$${\bf d}_\infty ((t,\omega),(t',\omega')) := |t-t'| + \|\omega_{.\wedge t}-{\omega'}_{.\wedge t'}\|_{T^.}$$

where :

$$\|\omega\|_t := \sup_{0\leq s \leq t}|\omega_s|$$

What do the dots in $.\wedge t$ and $T^.$ signify?

Comment: The first one that you take the whole path (which is then taken only up to t thanks to the minimum and stays from there on constant). The norm is a norm on the path space. The second one that this is the end of the sentence (period).

Comment: @StephanSturm Thanks. I had failed to notice that some of the other equations also had periods marking the end of the sentence:)